# How can i add to menustrip a recent files menu like in visual studio: File > Recent Files?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

And when you move the mouse over Recent Files it will show open a list of recent opened files ?

```
private void recentFilesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
            item.Text = "your file name";
            item.Click += new EventHandler(yourEventHandler);
            recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item);
        }
```

This is my Recent Files menu click event.
But i'm not sure how to make it to remember the recent opened files even if i close my program and opend it again.

And how to make that when i move the mouse over the Recent Files menu it will open the list.

Comment: Ok changing from click event to mouse enter event make the trick so when moving the mouse over Recent Files open the list of files. But two problems: 1. Only when i move the mouse over the Recent Files then i see this small arrow to the right but i want like in visua lstudio to see this small arrow to the right already. 2. How to keep/remember the opened files and keep it in a list ?

Comment: Ok solved the problem with the arrow.  I moved the item instance from the mouse enter event to the top of the form and  i moved the line: recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item); to the constructor. This did the trick. Now i need to find how to remember opened recent files make list of it and show it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Just create a simple `txt` file in your root application folder named `RecentFiles.txt`.
2. Whenever you open a new file add it to that list with its complete path.
3. When you open your application, just read the file and populate `DropdownList` or wherever you want to show that list.

You can also limit the recent to 5 or 10 items by a simple logic:

- Read file and populate the `List`(you can use string type list)
- Remove the last item of the `List`
- Add current file path as the first item of `List`
- And then save all item line by line to the file(override the file text, not append to it)

You can refer to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32154/Create-a-Recent-File-List-Menu-and-Save-to-File) as a practical example suggested by **[Jens Horstmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4435719/jens-horstmann)**

Comment: How about using a StringCollection variable in my.settings to store the paths of recent files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `Registry key`  to save the destinations of the most recent files or write them to a simple text file and read them from there at application start.